# Android ProgressDialog while selecting and deselecting checkboxes using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm a newbie to Android and I'm having some problems with the AsyncTask class. I have a lot of (over 100) check boxes which I want to select or deselect with a "select all" check box.
Unfortunately this takes quite some time, noticeable for the user, so I want to use the ProgressDialog to show that the selecting is in progress.

Now I know that updates of the UI elements are supposed to be done in the UI thread so I have the selecting code in the onProgressUpdate method but the ProgressDialog doesn't show up not until the processing (select or deselecting all checkboxes) is finished...

How is this supposed to be done? Is there any workaround or any other solution? I also tried to go through all the check boxes in the doInBackground() method but I get lots of weird errors (I guess it's because of the UI).

This is my code:

```
customPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object object) {
          new CbSelection().execute(preference);
          return true;
      }
});


private class CbSelection extends AsyncTask<Preference, Boolean, Void> {   

          private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Preferences.this);

          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {   
              Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..."); 
              Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
              Dialog.setCancelable(true);
              Dialog.show();   
          }   

          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Preference... pref) {   

              PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen)getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter().getItem(2);

              Preference preference = pref[0];
              if(preference.getKey().compareTo("select_all") == 0){
                  publishProgress(true);
              } 
              return null; 
          }   

          @Override
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... ok) {
              if(ok[0]== true) {
                  PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen)getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter().getItem(2);
                  for(int i = 0; i < screen.getPreferenceCount(); ++i) {
                      //Dialog.show();
                       /* select or deselect all checkboxes here... */
                  }

              }
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {   
              Dialog.cancel(); 
          }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you create and show the dialog before executing the `AsyncTask`? That's the way it usually is used:

```
private ProgressDialog Dialog;
customPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object object) {
          Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Preferences.this);
          Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..."); 
          Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
          Dialog.setCancelable(true);
          Dialog.show();   

          new CbSelection().execute(preference);
          return true;
      }
});
private class CbSelection extends AsyncTask<Preference, Boolean, Void> {   

          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Preference... pref) {   
              PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen)getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter().getItem(2);

              Preference preference = pref[0];
              if(preference.getKey().compareTo("select_all") == 0){
                  publishProgress(true);
              } 
              return null; 
          }   

          @Override
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... ok) {
              if(ok[0]== true) {
                  PreferenceScreen screen = (PreferenceScreen)getPreferenceScreen().getRootAdapter().getItem(2);
                  for(int i = 0; i < screen.getPreferenceCount(); ++i) {
                      /* select or deselect all checkboxes here... */
                  }

              }
          }

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {   
              Dialog.dismiss(); 
          }   
}
```

Comment: Still the same... the ProgressDialog shows up when the processing is finished.